# iBooks margin is a waste of screen space

Tags: books, epub

[image]On my 7.9" iPad Mini Retina, I'd like to use the full screen to shown content. Currently, the iBooks app simply wastes too much screen space on left/right margins.

Is there an alternative for reading ePUBs, say, to have an option to define margin size?

Comment: Screenshot please?

Comment: @Robuust screen shot added

Comment: Do you want to read EPUBs purchased from Apple? If you do, then there's no (legal) alternative, as only iBooks will read files protected by Apple's DRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a comparison of various iOS e-book readers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_iOS_e-book_reader_software).

Marvin comes with very flexible margin settings:

[image]

Comment: Assuming it's not bought via Apple?

Answer (score 2):

Open up the Settings app > iBooks > Full Justification